# php if statement to check if field is empty

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if mysql entry is empty in PhP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591611/how-to-check-if-mysql-entry-is-empty-in-php)

I'm trying to run a seemingly simply if statement, however, my PHP skills are not that great.

I am querying data from a single MySQL table and I want to run a statement that detects if a field is empty or not, if it's not I want it to display something, if it is, to not display anything.

Also, I'm not sure if it's possible to put this in an echo or not?

EDIT:************************
Here's the code to make things easier:

I may have done something wrong. Here is my code to explain things a little easier

'

```
if (!$result) {
    exit('<p>Error performing query: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
}
//creating the table w/ headers
echo '
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
            <th style="width:90px"><strong><a href="other-items.php?order=oc_retailer">Retailer</a></strong></th>
            <th style="width:90px"><strong>Files</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>';  
// Display each item
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '
    <tr>
        ...
        <td style="width:90px">' . $row['oc_retailer'] .'</td>
        <td style="width:90px"> this is where I want to if statement to go</td>


              ';
  }     
  echo '</table>';

  ?>'
```

Comment: Check this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591611/how-to-check-if-mysql-entry-is-empty-in-php

Same issue as asked.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `empty()` function which will check to see if anything is there.

The `isset()` checks for a null (boolean==false) on the field - which you can also use.

```
if(empty($row['yourColumn']))
{
    // it's empty!
    echo "Nada in the field!.\n";
}
else
{
    // Do stuff with the field
}
```

Edit: I think this is what you mean:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    if(!empty($row['oc_retailer']))
    {
    echo '
        <tr>
        ...
        <td style="width:90px"> this is where I want to if statement to go</td>
        ';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '
        <tr>
        ...
        <td style="width:90px">Ruh ohes! The Row was Empty!</td>
        ';
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for "correct" curly braces

Comment: @tubaguy50035 A few lines of extra code for ease of reading, it's worth it. Of course, I am also a fan of the ternary here and there :)

Comment: I've edited my original post to make things easier. I tried the code in the line that says "this is where I want to if statement to go"

Comment: I think *Empty* will through a warning if the string is empty, not sure :?

Comment: @Sourav No, `empty()` will return `true` if the string is empty – that is the purpose of that construct.

Comment: This doesn't work in a mysql_fetch_array  echo does it?

Answer (score 2):

> I am querying data from a single MySQL table and I want to run a statement that detects if a field is empty or not, if it's not I want it to display something, if it is, to not display anything.

So, you have a resultset which is an array, I reckon? In which case you'd want to check that the value is not equal to an empty string:

```
if($resultset['fieldname']===' '){
  echo 'fieldname was empty';
}
```

Please mind that the answer with isset is actually invalid: the value will always be set, because the field exists in the resultset, it's just an empty string by default.

**EDIT**: I was mistaken about the `empty( )` call, it appears to check for `isset($var) && !$var`. Still, because you have control over what columns you query, there's no need for the isset part and I'd advice against using `empty( )` in this situation.

Comment: "mind that the answers with isset and empty are actually invalid" No, only those with `isset()`. `empty()` does what you are doing by a comparison; but by checking for type equality too, you are using more processing power.

Comment: @feeela See my edit, I rectified that quite quickly ;)

Comment: @feeela Hm. My benchmarks show that using empty( ) is actually faster than direct comparison, even if we're doing a loose check (`==`). Still, it's micro-optimalisation and by using `=== ''`, the purpose is more clear (to me, anyway).

Comment: I get this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/jkogden/public_html/includes/dbstuff/other-items.php on line 194"
when using this code, note that I'm showing a clipping:
http://snipplr.com/view/66476/php-problem-1/

Comment: @Berry Langerak I've nerver said that using `empty()` is slower. And it is a matter of taste, but to me `empty()` is the more clear variant ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After getting  the data from MySQL try

```
if (!isset($data[0]))
 echo 'Input some data';
```

or

```
if (strlen($data[0])<1)
 echo 'Input some data';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using `mysql_query`, you can use

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 echo "There's Data";
}
```

Check [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

But it's better to just use prepared statement.

PDO uses [PDO::rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Mysqli uses [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Use of that extension is discouraged

Comment: -1 because the poster is asking about columns rather than rows

Comment: This will find a lack of resultset, but not if a column is empty?